# Skype for Consumer SDK(Skype4COM) change Default Audio Output and Input C# for Bluetooth Devices

Tags: c#, audio, bluetooth, skype, skype4com

I'm providing an interface to users to easily switch between different Audio Devices in Skype.

```
  I'm able to change the Skype Audio Input & Out using Skype4COM as below:
Skype _client=new Skype();
//outDevice=Headset Earphone (Plantronics C320-M) ->Works fine
//outDevice=Speaker/HP (Realtek High Definition Audio Device) ->Works fine
_client.Settings.AudioIn = inDevice;
_client.Settings.AudioOut = outDevice;
```

Headset Earphone (Plantronics C320-M) is the friendly name obtained using MMDevice (NAudio).
This works fine for Internal Speaker, Plantronics Headset etc. But for a Bluetooth speakers, it does not work. When I look at the settings of Skype, I see some number appended to the Bluetooth [image: Skype Audio Settings Screen]Speaker, which I'm not sure what this number is.
When I set as below, the Audio is routed correctly to JBL Bluetooth Speaker:

```
_client.Settings.AudioOut=Headset (JBL GO Hands-Free) JBL GO(202764376855473)
```

the question is, How do I get the number 202764376855473? What it is?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!
It is Decimal value of DeviceAddress property,
DeviceAddress = {B869C2A7D3B1}
Decimal(B869C2A7D3B1)=202764376855473

:-)

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: There should be a (hollow) check mark right underneath the vote up/down arrows, just left of the words "share edit flag". Click that checkmark to accept.